# How to find 2nd maximum number within c++ loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find out the second maximum value through conditional loop. I am getting 0 every time as second maximum value. Where is my mistake or how can i do that?

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int sum=0,n, c=1;
    int second_max=0;
    float avg;
    int max, min;
    cin >> n;
    sum = sum + n;
    max = min = n;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        cin >> n;
        if (n==0)
        break;
        sum =sum+n;
        c++;
        if (max < n)
            max = n;
        if(second_max<n && max!=n)    //code for finding second highest value
            second_max = n;
        if (min>n)
            min = n;
    }
             cout << "sum: " << sum<<'\n';
             avg = float(sum)/c;
             cout << "average: " << avg<<'\n';
             cout << "maximum no: " << max<<'\n';
             cout << "minimum no: " << min <<'\n';
             cout << "2nd maximum no: " << second_max << '\n';  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    if (max < n)
    {
        second_max = max; // the old max becomes second_max
        max = n; // max gets the new 'n' value 
    }
    if(second_max < n && n < max)
    {
        second_max = n;
    }
```

The problem is that you weren't shifting the old "max" value to "second_max" whenever max increased. So second_max just wasn't being updated in cases where the numbers kept increasing (max would be changed, never second_max).

Comment: I needed to edit the second if statement a little, because it would give an error if you typed in a value of *exactly* max later (second_max would then be equal to max).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you find a new max, you should set it to second max. Also ot should have else statement if max is changed only once and second max is changed.

```
while (n != 0)
{
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0)
        break;
    sum = sum + n;
    c++;
    if (max < n)
    {
        second_max = max;
        max = n;
    }
    if(second_max < n && n < max)
    {
        second_max = n;
    }


    if (min>n)
        min = n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num[10]{};

int max = 0;

int m2x = 0;

//to input the numbers from user

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    cin >> num[i];

}
// find the max number 
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (num[j]>=max) {
        max = num[j];
 }
}
// to find lastmax number
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    if (max == num[x]) {
        continue;
    }
    if (num[x] >= m2x) {
        m2x = num[x];
    }
}
cout << m2x << endl;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).